# Pra que serve a propriedade clip?

Tags: css, css3

Estava dando uma olhada em um código onde ensinava algumas técnicas para criar uma tabela responsiva.

Me deparei com o uso da propriedade `clip`, seguida do valor `rect(0 0 0 0);`.

Então me surgiu essa duvida:

**Para que serve a propriedade `clip`?**

<sub>Nota:A pergunta em si não tem nada a ver com elementos responsivos, mas foi apenas a ocasião onde vi o uso de clip pela primeira vez</sub>.

Comment: A propriedade `clip` serve para definir a área vísivel de um elemento fixo na página. Aplicado à uma imagem, poderia ser comparado com uma ação de *crop*. Os quatro valores em `rect` definem a área visível: `rect(<top> <right> <bottom> <left>)`. Como isso pode ser aplicado à tabelas responsivas (e utilizar todos os valores 0), não sei dizer.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Até onde eu sei é comunmente usado na responsividade para cortar grandes imagens (geralmente pelas laterais) quando há conteúdo que pode ser escondido para não ter que se diminuir a imagem. Ou seja, ao diminuir a tela, as vezes é preferível cortar conteúdo irrelevante das laterais ao invés de diminuir a imagem.

Comment: Legal a pergunta, particularmente desconhecia essa propriedade.

Comment: As duas respostas já mencionavam que estava obsoleto...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`CLIP` significa RECORTAR, ou seja , ela recorta o conteúdo de um box.

- A sintaxe é:

`.container {clip: rect (top, right, bottom, left);}`

onde:

•   `container` é o elemento HTML cujo conteúdo será recortado;

•   `clip` é a propriedade recortar;

•   `rect(top , right , bottom , left)`  é a função para recortar cujos parâmetros são as coordenadas para o recorte expressas em medidas CSS .

*Imagine que precise cortar a área destacada na figura a seguir com suas respectivas coordenadas:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso o código `CSS` ficaria assim:

```
.container {clip: rect (40px, 150px, 260px, 80px);
```

- Onde `rect` é os parâmetros para o recorte da imagem.

O resultado do recorte dessa imagem é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Perceba que a área da imagem que foi recortada permanece com seu
  espaço em branco no documento.

Obs: A propriedade `clip` só funciona para elementos posicionados de maneira fixed ou absolute. Lembrando que na documentação da [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/clip) tem a seguinte afirmação.

> Este recurso foi removido dos padrões da Web. Embora alguns
>   navegadores ainda possam apoiá-lo, ele está em processo de queda.
>   Evite usá-lo e atualizar o código existente, se possível; Consulte a
>   [tabela de compatibilidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip#Browser_compatibility) na parte inferior desta página para orientar
>   sua decisão. Esteja ciente de que esse recurso pode deixar de
>   funcionar a qualquer momento.

Use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) em vez disso!

Referencia:

- http://www.maujor.com/blog/2006/06/26/a-propriedade-css-clip/

Answer (score 9):

A propriedade `clip` serve para  recortar um elemento absolutamente posicionado, serve para os casos em que uma imagem está inserida dentro de um elemento menor que ela, nesse caso podemos utilizar a propriedade `clip` para recortar a imagem, ajustando ao tamanho do elemento pai, resumidamente, **a propriedade define a área do elemento que ficará visível**.

### **Ex:**

```
/*rect(top,right,bottom,left)*/
clip: rect(110px, 160px, 170px, 60px);
```

### **Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fonte img: [css-tricks clip](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)

### **Observações:**

> De acordo com a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/clip) a propriedade está **obsoleta** e deve-se utilizar a propriedade `clip-path` em seu lugar.

O valor **default** da propriedade é `auto`, ou seja, não limita a área de visualização do elemento.

A propriedade clip só funciona em elementos com `position:absolute` ou `position:fixed`. Não funcionará com `relative` ou `static`.

Para informações sobre compatibilidade: [w3schools css clip](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)

Segue um exemplo funcional da propriedade, definindo a área visível de uma imagem, para ver a imagem completa basta comentar a propriedade `clip`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
      clip: rect(20px, 130px, 180px, 30px);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1196566139/CRV_-_Urso_comptd.jpg" width="200" height="300">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: De acordo com [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/clip) esta propriedade está obsoleta e deve usar-se [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) no lugar. Talvez seja interessante adicionar isso à resposta.

Comment: Perfeitamente @AndersonCarlosWoss, adicionado à resposta.

Comment: E também pode confirmar a sequência dos parâmetros de `rect`? Eu encontrei aqui `<top> <right> <bottom> <left>` e você colocou `left` e `right` trocados no comentário do código.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, novamente, muito obrigado pelas observações, corrigido.